# Change all views text color in PreferenceActivity programmatically

Tags: android

I want to change text color of all view of PreferenceActivity when a SwitchPreference state changes.

prefs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
      android:summary="Settings"
      android:title="Settings" >

        <SwitchPreference
          android:key="NightMode"
          android:summary="dark and light"
          android:title="Night Mode" />

...

    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

PrefsActivity.java

```
public class PrefsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

        boolean nightMode = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("NightMode", false);
        if(nightMode){

         //I want to change text color here

        }
```

}
}

I can change backgroundColor of layout this way:

```
getListView().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this , R.color.colorBackground));
```

but how to change text color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to change the text color is to call `textviewinstance.setTextColor(color)`.  You'd need to do that to every view independently though.

The best way to do this is to use the android theme system.  If you set the theme before calling `setContentView`, all those views will be created with that theme.  Make a theme with the text color you want for nightmode.  When nightmode is selected, call recreate() to kill your activity and start a new one, just like what happens on configuration changes.  Then in onCreate of the new instance, check if night mode is on and select your theme before setting the content view by calling `setTheme(theme)`.